# how to wget a file on a remote server connected using ssh?

Tags: ssh, wget, file-server

I am connected to my university computer using SSH as follows :

```
sudo ssh server@A.B.C.D
```

However once connected, I'm not able to download any file on the server using wget like this :

```
server_user@server:~$ wget http://example.com/somefile
```

If I do that, I get following error:

```
--2020-07-28 10:14:46--  https://example.com/somefile
Resolving example.com (example.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘example.com’
```

Also I'm not able to install any package using pip on the remote server. How shoud I do these things? Thanks in advance :)

PS : of course the address is not the `example.com`. I've just used it temporarily here for the example purpose. It is a real http address from which I can download file locally using wget, but doing it on server raises the error reported above.

Answer (score 0):

To know the *exact* problem I'll need more details about the server.
But actually it just boils down to a DNS-problem.

Contact the admin of this server and mention that there is a problem with DNS and that resolving the `A` and `AAAA` records of `example.com` fail.

Temporary solution: replace `example.com` by the IP of the server.
(Running a `ping example.com` on your computer will show you the ip)

**Edit:** You mentioned that you also have a problem with installing python modules (with `pip`). This is because of the same reason, pip will try to download them from a website of which it only knows the hostname and not the ip.

**Edit 2:** You can also do some research yourself on why resolving fails but i would be careful here !
Some admins like a bit of help from users, others can get really angry when users start snooping around.
When in doubt: don't do it.
Anyway, here are some commands that can provide you more info:

- `dig -t A example.com @8.8.8.8 | grep -v '^;' | grep A` (should show you the ip of example.com)
- `dig -t A example.com | grep -v '^;' | grep A` (should show the same)
- `resolvectl status | grep Server` (should show you the dnsservers of your university)
- `systemctl status systemd-resolved` (should be active)
- `journalctl -u systemd-resolve` (should not contain errors)

Comment: Depending on what the server is _supposed_ to do, it's also possible it's in a private subnet with a DNS server that only resolves internal domains on purpose.

Comment: Ulrich Schwarz is certainly correct. But it would suprise me if this the case here. (I am a admin at a university myself. All our servers that regular bachelor students can access with ssh resolve external names)

Answer (score 0):

The server has no DNS resolution - perhaps it has intentionally no access to the internet. But you can use `scp` to upload files to the server.